# store the input value when clicking on a link

Tags: php

i have read about $_POST and $_GET for a form to get an input value but i think my situation its abit harder.

Let me explain you: 
I have this condition:

```
if (!isset($_GET['submit'])){
            echo('Introduceti numarul de articole pe care doriti sa le cumparati in casuta alaturata <input type="number" name="stoc" id="stoc" value=""> apoi apasati <a href="?submit=true" name=submit" class="btn">Continuare</a> daca doriti sa cumparati produsul. Anuntul nu va mai fi activ pe site!<br/>
                ');
        }
        else{
             !!! When i get here i need to know the value of the inbut above
        }
```

My input and link tag are:

```
<input type="number" name="stoc" id="stoc" value=""> 
<a href="?submit=true" name=submit" class="btn">Continuare</a>
```

How can i do that?

Comment: `$var = $_GET['submit']`

Comment: You have to include a `<form>` because inputs by themselves do nothing: go read a basic HTML tutorial on forms.

Comment: Tried already... it says that the variable is NULL when i click on a tag

Comment: also i used form with metod get or post and tried to store a session like so : $_SESSION['input_value'] = $_POST(or $_GET)['stoc'];

Comment: When you use a form you use `<input type='submit' />` not a link.  Links make you lose all the form data.

Comment: @Proless watch my code.

Comment: @Proless Okey i will do it for you code then, if you understand when you say name="whatever" thats the name of the variable so you only have to call it like $_GET['stoc'] for your example.

Comment: @Proless the submit is a input type not a link, is like <input type="submit">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you have this for the html code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="welcome.php" method="get">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then you can do this on the php:

```
if (!isset($_GET['submit'])){
            echo('
                <h1>Introduceti numarul de articole pe care doriti sa le cumparati in casuta alaturata <input type="number" name="stoc" id="stoc" value=""> apoi apasati <a href="?submit=true" name=submit" class="btn">Continuare</a> daca doriti sa cumparati produsul. Anuntul nu va mai fi activ pe site!</h1><br/>
                ');
        }
        else{
             // When i get here i need to know the value of the inbut above
            echo "Welcome ".$_GET['name']."<br>";
            echo "Your email is: ".$_GET['email']."<br>";
        }
```

For more examples you can visit [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: you missed an opening `"` one the first of the two bottom lines

Comment: Sorry, im fixing it, thanks

Comment: aint any way to use a link like i did in echo instead input tag? if i use your way it doesnt go onto else...

Comment: @Proless You have to create a file called welcome.php paste the php code that i wrote and save it in the same directory of the html file and it will work excellent :)

Comment: @Proless please write me if it didn't work

Comment: I get it work like so: form method changed to post coz get wasnt empty. And i changed the condition to if (empty($_POST)){}else{}

Comment: @Proless im glad to hear that you could solve it. Keep practicing :)